# Images in iPhone simulator do not take up same real estate as on real device

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

**Background**

I need to get a square image to fill a table cell side to side, with a small margin, and have it work across all devices.

The approach I've taken to deal with different devices is to programmatically set the row height in the table based on device and use AspectFit to cause the image to fill the row -- which works well when I know what value to set the row height to.  It only takes a couple of guesses to get it right.

**Problem**

The way the image looks in the simulator is different than the way it appears on a real device, making testing impossible on the simulator and requiring real devices to be certain.

Is this a known problem with images and the simulator?  Is there some workaround or setting that I am missing?

I would like to get the simulator presentation to match the device presentation with respect to images so I can test effectively without access to a slew of physical devices.

Thanks in advance.

**Reference Images**

The first image is from the iPhone 6 simulator. The second (correct one) is from a real iPhone 6 device.  You would not guess from the simulator that the image is correct on the actual device.

We have also seen this problem with other simulators, such iPhone 7 simulator, and iPhone SE simulator, so we assume it is a problem with all simulators.

[image: Here is a screenshot from the simulator]

[image: Here is one from a real device]

**Source Code for this controller**

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import GRDB
import SwiftPhotoGallery

class SpeciesDescriptionController: UITableViewController, SwiftPhotoGalleryDataSource, SwiftPhotoGalleryDelegate {

    let tableCell = "TableCell"
    var target_id : Int64 = 0
    var item_scanned : Bool = false
    let scanned = Scanned()

    var species_array = [Species]()
    var species : Species!

    var primary_image : Image!
    var image_names = [String]()

    let favorites = Favorites()


    @IBAction func toggle_favorites(_ sender: Any) {
        if (favorites.check(species_id: species.id!) == true) {
            favorites.remove(species_id: species.id!)
        } else {
            favorites.add(content_id: species.id!, table_name: "Species", display_name: species.display_name)
        }
        set_favorites_status()
    }


    @IBOutlet weak var favorites_status: UIBarButtonItem!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        loadSpeciesDescription()
        loadPrimaryImage()
        setTitle()
        formatTable()
        set_favorites_status()
        if item_scanned == true {
            scanned.add(content_id: species.id!, table_name: "Species", display_name: species.display_name)
        }

        let modelName = UIDevice.current.modelName
        print("\n\nThe model name is: \(modelName)\n\n")
    }


    private func set_favorites_status() {
        if (favorites.check(species_id: species.id!) == true) {
            favorites_status.image = UIImage(named: "glyphicons-50-star")
        } else {
            favorites_status.image = UIImage(named: "glyphicons-49-star-empty")
        }
    }


    private func loadSpeciesDescription() {
        species = try! dbQueue.inDatabase { db in
            try Species.fetchOne(db, key: target_id)
        }
    }

    private func loadPrimaryImage() {
        let visibleIdColumn = Column("visible_id")
        let visibleTypeColumn = Column("visible_type")
        let primaryPhotoColumn = Column("primary_photo")
        let request = Image.filter(visibleIdColumn == species.id )
            .filter(visibleTypeColumn == "Species")
            .filter(primaryPhotoColumn == "t")
        primary_image = try! dbQueue.inDatabase { db in
            try request.fetchOne(db)
        }
    }


    func formatTable() {
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero) // deny empty table rows
    }


    func setTitle() {
        self.title =  species.display_name
    }


    func species_names() -> String {
        var all_names: String = ""
        let scientific_names = "Scientific: \(species.scientific_name)\n"
        let common_names = "Common: \(species.common_name)"
        let other_names = "\nNoongar: \(species.other_names)"

        all_names = scientific_names + common_names
        if (other_names != "\nNoongar: ") {
            all_names = all_names + other_names
        }
        return all_names
    }

    /////////////////// Table //////////////////////////////

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 6
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        var title : String = ""
        switch section {
        case 0 : title = " " // must have blank to print the blank section header
        case 1 : title = "Names"
        case 2 : title = "Audio"
        case 3 : title = "Identification"
        case 4 : title = "Description"
        case 5 : title = "Range"
        default: title = "Not defined..."
        }
        return title
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
    {
        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            return CGFloat(row_height_for_device())
        } else {
            return  UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        }
    }

    func row_height_for_device() -> Int {
        switch UIDevice.current.modelName {
        case "iPhone SE" :
            return 290  //confirmed to work with SE
        case "iPhone 6", "iPhone 6s"   :
            return 290  // confirmed to work with 6
        case "iPhone 7" :
            return 348  //
        case "iPhone 8"   :
            return 348  //
        case "iPhone 6 Plus", "iPhone 6s Plus","iPhone 7 Plus", "iPhone 8 Plus"   :
            return 380
        case "iPhone X" :
            return 400
        default:
            // handles 2G, 3G, 3GS, 4, 4s, 5, 5s, 5c, SE
            // confirmed to work with SE
            return 290
        }
    }



    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: tableCell) as UITableViewCell?
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: tableCell)
        }

        cell!.imageView?.image = nil
        cell!.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        cell!.textLabel?.text = nil
        cell!.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
        cell!.textLabel?.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
        cell!.textLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)

        switch indexPath.section {
        case 0 :
            let image_file_name = "primary_\(primary_image.image_file_name)"
            print("The image the app is looking for is called: \(image_file_name)")
            cell!.imageView?.image =  UIImage(named: image_file_name)
        case 1 : cell!.textLabel?.text = species_names()
        case 2 :
            cell!.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "glyphicons-169-ear-plugs")
            cell!.textLabel?.text = "1 Minute Audio Summary"
        case 3 : cell!.textLabel?.text = species.identification
        case 4 : cell!.textLabel?.text = species.description
        case 5 : cell!.textLabel?.text = species.range
        default :  cell!.textLabel?.text = ""

        }
        return cell!
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if indexPath.section == 2 {
            textToSpeech(audio_summary: species.audio_summary)
        }
        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            show_gallery(species_id: species.id!)
        }

    }

    func standard_alert(_ alertTitle: String, alertMessage: String) -> Void {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: alertTitle, message: alertMessage, preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("OK", comment: "Ok"), style: .default, handler: nil))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


    func bail_out() {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "no_content", sender: nil)
    }

    func textToSpeech(audio_summary : String)
    {
        let synth = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
        var myUtterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: "")
        myUtterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: audio_summary)
        myUtterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "en-AU")
        synth.speak(myUtterance)
    }


    ///////////

    func show_gallery(species_id: Int64) {
        // load_image_names(species_id: species_id)
        let image_file_name = "large_primary_" + primary_image.image_file_name
        image_names = [image_file_name]  // array of one item for now
        let gallery = SwiftPhotoGallery(delegate: self, dataSource: self)
        gallery.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        gallery.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.gray.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
        gallery.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.white
        gallery.hidePageControl = true
        present(gallery, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


    // MARK: SwiftPhotoGalleryDataSource Methods

    func numberOfImagesInGallery(gallery: SwiftPhotoGallery) -> Int {
        return image_names.count
    }

    func imageInGallery(gallery: SwiftPhotoGallery, forIndex: Int) -> UIImage? {
        return UIImage(named: image_names[forIndex])
    }

    // MARK: SwiftPhotoGalleryDelegate Methods

    func galleryDidTapToClose(gallery: SwiftPhotoGallery) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


} // class
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with a difference between "simulator and device." The issue is that you are using a *different* simulator than your device. Are all your images the same size, or different sizes?

Comment: The simulator matches the device: iPhone 6 simulator.  iPhone 6 device.  I double checked.  The images are cropped to be all the same size and shape (square and 480x480).

Comment: Hmmm... something odd is going on then. As you notice, disregarding the image, even the *text* in your label is laying out differently - the "Common:..." line is wrapping on the device image, but not on the simulator image. Do you have some code that is making adjustments? Or is this all done with auto-layout and constraints?

Comment: I added the complete source code for the controller.  Note: I briefly commented out the device model logic and returned 290 no matter what.  The problem continued -- it looks right on the iPhone 6 actual device, but not in the simulator.  (I did this to make sure the simulator got the same value as the device.  Then I returned the source code to the version you see now.

Comment: I think you may be trying to solve the wrong problem... but, first, can you post a different screen-shot of your simulator? Your simulator image is `606 x 1079` and your device image is `640 x 1136` ... when running the simulator, you should be able to select `Window -> Pixel Accurate` and then you can save the screen-shot at the same dimensions... makes it easier to compare the two.

Comment: Your comment pointed me in the right direction.  I had my device zoomed.  When I unzoomed it, everything matches.  You should get the credit for the answer, so if you post the answer I'll mark it.

Comment: Also...do you have a suggestion on how to solve the right problem?

Comment: Sure... I'll add an answer with some additional comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per comments discussion, the original issue was due to the Device display options being set to Zoom. Once Zoom is turned off, the Simulator again matches the device.

On a separate note... I'm assuming the goal is to have the image centered in the cell, with a bit of padding (20-pts or so) on each side, while maintaining a square shape? If so...

I'd suggest creating a custom cell class.

Add a `UIImageView` with constraints of `Top: 0, Bottom: 0, Leading 20, Trailing: 20`. Then set the image view to have a `1:1` ratio constraint.

Now, the image view will "auto" stretch to the width of the cell (minus the padding) and auto-layout will set the Height to match the Width. No need to do any manual calculating / setting of row height.